# How I can get info countries with allowed sms-sending from twilio.com in PHP?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

How I can get countries via API with allowed sms-sending from twilio.com in PHP?

On image below highlighted what I need. Is this possible via API?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid we don't have an API for that information. You can find out which countries' numbers support features like SMS from this page though: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183068-Twilio-international-phone-number-availability-and-their-capabilities